# Using TiffBitmapEncoder with Gray32Float

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, bitmap, tiff

I'm trying to create a 32 BPP gray scale tiff using [this code which I found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969817%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
BitmapSource image = BitmapSource.Create(
                width,
                height,
                96,
                96,
                PixelFormats.Gray32Float,
                null,
                pixels,
                stride);

FileStream stream = new FileStream("test file.tif", FileMode.Create);

TiffBitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Compression = TiffCompressOption.None;
var bitmapFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(image);
encoder.Frames.Add(bitmapFrame);
encoder.Save(stream);
```

The file gets created and the image looks correct when I open it, but the file properties says that it is a 16 BPP (0-65536) image not a 32 bit floating point as specified by the [Gray32Float](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pixelformats.gray32float%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parameter.

I've confirmed the file format is 16 BPP by looking at the file properties in windows explorer and by opening the file in [ImageJ](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/features.html)

I can create 32 BPP tiffs in Paint.Net and ImageJ, to confirm that format is supported.

Anyone know why the .Net [TiffBitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.tiffbitmapencoder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is creating the wrong type?

Answer (score 3):

Under the hood, .Net uses the [Windows Imaging Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (WIC).  WIC supports reading of TIFFs in Gray32Float (GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppGrayFloat in WIC) but **not writing**.  Take a look at the WIC [Native Pixel Formats Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee719797%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#tiff_native_codec).  I had the same experience discovering the image was written as Gray16.

This is very frustrating.  I've been attempting to writes some scientific data using Gray32Float, but I have not been successful.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I tried, and almost made it, but still - doesn't work correctly:

What I have here is a solution which saves as 32bit, using [TiffLib](http://www.simplesystems.org/libtiff/), but the value range is somehow not correct.

I save an image in float range of -0.5 to 3, and imageJ reads it as 32 bit, BUT the range is ~-1000K to ~3000K...

I tried using TiffLib adding the following functions:
public static void Write32BitTiff_(string path, int W, int H, float[] data, ref byte[] FileData, int numPage = 0)
{
var numBytes = sizeof(float);
var size = H * W * numBytes;
byte[] arr = null;

```
        arr = new byte[size];
        var ctr = 0;
        byte[] floatVal;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i += numBytes)
        {
            try
            {
                float val = data[ctr++];
                floatVal = BitConverter.GetBytes(val);

                for (int j = 0; j < numBytes; j++)
                    arr[i + j] = floatVal[j];
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception eee) { }
        }


        Tiff t = openTiff(path, W, H, numPage, numBytes * 8);
        t.WriteRawStrip(0, arr, size);

        t.Close();
        t.Dispose();
    }
```

Where "OpenTiff" looks like this:

```
private static Tiff openTiff(string path, int W, int H, int pageNum, int numBits, bool overrideFile = false)
    {

        Tiff t;
        int numberOfPages;
        if (!File.Exists(path) || overrideFile )
        {
            t = Tiff.Open(path, "w");
            numberOfPages = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            var start = DateTime.Now;
            t = Tiff.Open(path, "a");
            numberOfPages = t.NumberOfDirectories() + 1; ;
            numberOfPages = (pageNum > numberOfPages) ? pageNum : numberOfPages;
        }


        t.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH, W);
        t.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGELENGTH, H);
        const int NUM_CHANNELS = 1;//for RGB set 3. for ARGB set 4, not sure supported.
        t.SetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL, NUM_CHANNELS);
        t.SetField(TiffTag.BITSPERSAMPLE, numBits);
        t.SetField(TiffTag.PHOTOMETRIC, Photometric.MINISBLACK);

        t.SetField(TiffTag.SUBFILETYPE, FileType.PAGE);
        t.SetField(TiffTag.PAGENUMBER, pageNum, numberOfPages);
        t.SetDirectory((short)pageNum);
```

}

So if this might help someone, or if someone could find the "bug" with it - this would be great!